# Expand background jQuery trigger not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The goal is when you click on the image behind the red square, the red square expands to the whole webpage.

[image]

But the moment after you clicked on the image the transition plays like this...

[image]

[image]

...and ended like this.

[image]

when you click on the red expanded square it transitions perfectly back to this, but in a different shape not where it was at the beginning.

[image]

```js
$(".img-placeholder").on("click", function() {
  $(".img-placeholder").addClass("w-full");
  $(".expandBG").toggleClass("content-portf");
  $(".text-portf").delay(500).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.img-placeholder {
  width: 24vw;
  height: 178px;
  margin-top: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 99%;
  border: solid #08a6ff 1px;
  display: grid;
}

.expandBG {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
  background-color: #ff0022;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.closeit {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

.text-portf {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-portf {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ff0022;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-placeholder">
  <div class="expandBG">
    <div class="content-portf text-portf" style="display: none;">
      <div>(CONTENT HERE)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotating-imgs animation">
    <img class="animation_image" src="imgs/rotating-img1.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I added `.w-full { width: 100%; }` in jQuery to expand the red square to the full width of the whole webpage and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my version of the [code](https://codepen.io/mankinchi/pen/qBpKaqN).

The change is quite small, just this

```
$(".text-portf").delay(500).fadeIn();
```

to this

```
$(".text-portf").delay(500).toggle();
```

If you debug your HTML tree in your code after you click the box twice, you will be able to see that `.expandBG` is fine. It's sticking to the correct sizing that you are giving it (50x50). The problem comes from your `.text-portf` still having the height of `50vw` (applied from `content-portf` CSS). It's basically overflowing the container `.expandBG`. You can see that yourself by adding

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to `.expandBG` css.

Comment: Thank you, but the red square need to expand out of the parent div to show full-screen of the webpage, not inside the parent div - hope that helps! Also when you close the red square it transitions to the center, but when you open it starts on the right instead of the center.

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg yeah. In my example, I only work on the expanding/collapsing part. In order to do full webpage, it would be better if you use `position: fixed` for the red box instead of manipulating the size of it like what you are doing now. Also, if you used `position: fixed`, then it doesn't need to be in any container element as well. Try searching for `modal` and see whether it's what you are looking for

Comment: The `position: fixed;` works! Going to see if I can work on the transition itself. It doesn't look perfect. Thank you!